# How to see debug() messages from contentscript.js while debugging a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, dom-events

I am debugging a Chrome extension off github. (https://github.com/artemave/translate_onhover)

I want to see the `debug()` messages that are in the code: like this one...

--------From contentscript.js------------

```
const hit_text_node = getExactTextNode(text_nodes, e)
if (!hit_text_node) {
  debug('hit between lines')
  return ''
}
```

I have tried:

In Chrome on a web page, I tried right-click verbose, but they don't appear.

[image]

I do see `console.log('jim103',word)` from devtools from `chrome://extensions background.js`

[image]

[image]

I also tried putting the word
`debugger;`
in both files, but it just caused a breakpoint in background.js, not the debug message I seek...

I know these two files are back/front separated... That's all I know.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have a built-in function called debug, which tells us that it's a custom one. We could also figure it out by trying to step-into that function during debugging (with F11 key). This leads us to trying to find its definition – and it's at the top of the file: const debug = require('debug')('transover'). The fact that the argument of `require` here is not a path, but just a name, tells us that this is a package – go to `package.json` and there it is: "debug": "^4.1.1". By default, NPM packages are downloaded from npmjs.com, let's head there and find the package – https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug. Its docs tell us that in the browser environment its behaviour is controlled by localStorage https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#browser-support. So all you have to do is type localStorage.debug = 'transover*' In the console for a particular site and reload the page. Debug messages will start appearing in the console.

-В Иванов

There are two outputs, back/front   background.js comes out in DevTools, but front=contentscript.js:debug() stuff comes out on the page.
Do right-click->Inspect and look on the right side.
[image]